# MouseEnter behaving like MouseOver in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the JQuery **mouseenter** listener, to listen for an event whenever a mouse enters over a panel.

```
$(this.outletSelectorPanel).mouseenter(function(event) {
    console.log('in');
    while (self.outletSelectorPanel.firstChild) {
        self.outletSelectorPanel.removeChild(self.outletSelectorPanel.firstChild);
    }
    self.outletSelectorPanel.appendChild(self.searchPanel);
});
```

FF and Chrome function correctly, but Internet Explorer treats it like a **mouseOver** event.
ie. the event fires every time the mouse moves over the panel. (console.log spits out 'in' continuously)

- Firstly this seems strange that IE would be so confused.
- Secondly does anyone have any idea how I fix this, or if there is another kind of mouse event i should be listening on?

js fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/8z9w2/

Comment: can you share some more context about how is it used? like the markup and where is this code resides

Comment: What version of IE and what version of jQuery?

Comment: ive added some more code... (maybe it is not removing the first child correctly). Ie8 and jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: have you tried `$(this.outletSelectorPanel).onmouseenter = function () {...}`

Comment: You can check on this documentation page of jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ -> you can test at the bottom of the page, it works well for me in IE7/8/9...

Comment: what we need is what is happening outside this function, from what function it is called? what is `outletSelectorPanel`? etc

Comment: yes u r right. i think there is more to it than just the event not firing correctly. will get back with more

Comment: I have a JSFiddle now : http://jsfiddle.net/8z9w2/